# Cannot find module 'autoprefixer' when running npx tailwindcss init -p command

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I'm using Vue 3 and trying to add tailwindcss into it from the following tutorial. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite#install-tailwind-via-npm

I have installed the dependencies using the following command,

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

But when I tried to create the configuration files using the following command

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

It is giving me the following error.

> npx: installed 83 in 5.2s Cannot find module 'autoprefixer' Require
> stack:
>
> - /~/.npm/_npx/33283/lib/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/cli/commands/build.js
> - /~/.npm/_npx/33283/lib/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/cli/commands/index.js
> - /~/.npm/_npx/33283/lib/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/cli/main.js
> - /~/.npm/_npx/33283/lib/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/cli.js

I don't know why `autoprefixer` is not detecting because I have already installed it.
Even the package.json have it.

```
{
  "name": "wooclime",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: try it out without flag `npx tailwindcss init`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim still same, what does that flag means?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of `-p` flag

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim ok, but still same error, don't know why it is happening. I think if I install the autoprefixer in the dependencies, instead of devDevependencies it will solve the issue.

Comment: Please solve it in the answer section, it easy to see. Anw upgrade node version work for me

Answer (score 46):

Run:

```
npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init -p
```

Answer (score 2):

Please uninstall run this command:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

After this module is uninstall, please run this command:

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following command using the tailwindcss cli with latest version an the flag `--postcss` or `-p`

```
npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init --postcss
```

Or follow these steps :

After installing that dependencies try to create the following files project root without running that command :

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

Then in your main CSS file add :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: I found an suggestion about updating the nodejs from this link. https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2831
I'm trying to update and let see if it solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I ran the command with node version 14.15.0.
Apparently using node 15.5 solved it for me. I think there's a problem with npm or something.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue

I downgrade the tailwindcss package to 1.0.5 from latest

Now it is working