# Tailwindcss 3 does not init on Windows 10

Tags: css, npm, tailwind-css, npx

Here is my history:

At home a installed tailwindcss and it simply works (My PC has Ubuntu Linux).

At work, I use Windows 10 and it just does not work at all. I am crazy to start a new project with tailwindcss!

Here is the error I've got (whem I run `npx tailwindcss init`):

```
PS C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.4.22-0\apache2\htdocs\b&t-cambio\wp-content\themes\btcambio> npx tailwindcss init
't-cambio\wp-content\themes\btcambio\node_modules\.bin\' it is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file. 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.4.22-0\apache2\htdocs\tailwindcss\lib\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I've verified if NPM in on my PATH and it sure is. I have used npm dozen of times before and there was no errors.

My npm, npx and node versions are:

```
$ npm --version && npx --version && node --version
8.3.0
8.3.0
v16.13.1
```

I have gone to all stackoverflow questions related to tailwind issues, and went through lots of forums, but with no success.

Someone here knows what is going on?

For now I just want to use pure CSS with tailwindcss, whith no preprocessors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh gosh! about 10 hours lost. I found in this question a solution: [Cannot find module 'autoprefixer' when running npx tailwindcss init -p command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259436/cannot-find-module-autoprefixer-when-running-npx-tailwindcss-init-p-command)

The error is something related to the tailwind\lib\cli so the solution is to run `npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init -p`

At the first run it will ask if you want to install the package. After that, it' works!

It the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) (step 4) Start *the Tailwind CLI build process* has the same command issue... so where the command is `tailwindcss`, use `tailwindcss-cli@latest` then the thing runs smoothly.

Comment: thanks for the simple solution. have been trying for 2hrs and thousands of times of reinstalling finally came across this. Thanks for the contribution